# Pegar objeto do JSON de forma dinâmica

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho jSON que criei e queria, de forma dinâmica pegar os array e objetos dentro dele

```
var json = [
    {'PHP': 
        [
            {'aula1':
                [
                'txt','O PHP é uma linguagem ...',
                'img','caminho','descrição'
                ]
            },
            {'aula2':
                [
                'txt','Nessa aula aprenderemos ...',
                'btn','Download','caminho','nome'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {'HTML':
        [
            {'aula1':
                [
                'txt','HTML significa linguagem ...'
                ]
            },
            {'aula2':
                [
                'txt','Nessa aula aprenderemos ...',
                'btn','Download','caminho','nome'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

algo como:

```
var materia = 'PHP'
var numMateria = 0
var aula = 'aula1'
var numAula = 0

for(i = 0; i < json.[indexMateria].materia[indexAula].aula.length; i++) {
    if(json.[indexMateria].materia[indexAula].aula[i] == 'txt') {
        document.write('<p>' + json.[indexMateria].materia[indexAula].aula[i+1] + '</p>')
        i += 1
    } else if(json.[indexMateria].materia[indexAula].aula[i] == 'img') {
        document.write('<img src="' + json.[indexMateria].materia[indexAula].aula[i+1] + '" alt="' + json.[indexMateria].materia[indexAula].aula[i+2] + '">')
        i += 2
    }
}
```

Só que quando eu uso `json[indexMateria].materia` ele busca por um objeto `materia` em vez de usar a variável `materia`

Alguém tem alguma ideia de o que fazer? Não tem problema alterar o json ou usar frameworks

Comment: O que você quer buscar exatamente?

Comment: os array dentro das dos objetos aula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito na resposta do avsinacio, você pode pegar o índice de um objeto em javascrit por meio do `[]`, fica mais ou menos assim

```js
var json = [
    {'PHP': 
        [
            {'aula1':
                [
                'txt','O PHP é uma linguagem ...',
                'img','caminho','descrição'
                ]
            },
            {'aula2':
                [
                'txt','Nessa aula aprenderemos ...',
                'btn','Download','caminho','nome'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {'HTML':
        [
            {'aula1':
                [
                'txt','HTML significa linguagem ...'
                ]
            },
            {'aula2':
                [
                'txt','Nessa aula aprenderemos ...',
                'btn','Download','caminho','nome'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }];
    
var indice1 = 0;
var materia = "PHP";
var indice2 = 0;
var aula = "aula1";

//Caso o objeto exista
if(typeof json[indice1][materia][indice2][aula] !== "undefined"){
      console.log(json[indice1][materia][indice2][aula]);
}
```

Comment: é isso mesmo valeu

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se entendi muito bem sua pergunta mas ao fazer:

```
json[indexMateria].materia
```

Você está exatamente buscando um objeto 'materia' no seu JSON.

Se eu entendi bem o seu objetivo, você deveria fazer algo do tipo:

```
json[indexMateria][materia]
```

Se possível detalhe um pouco mais o que quer fazer.

Comment: usando `[materia]` ele mostra esse erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: resumindo... tenho um json com um array de objetos matérias(HTML e PHP por exemplo), as matérias possuem um array de objetos aulas(aula1, aula2, ...) e as aulas possuem um array de conteudo. quero pegar esse conteudo e escrever no html

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam esse erro de Unexpected token foi causado pela mistura da bracket notation com a dot notation. Nos trechos onde tem `json.[indexMateria]` use apenas `json[indexMateria]`

Comment: ok, valeu pela ajuda cara

Answer (score -1):

Converta sua variável 'json' para Object e faça o tratamento necessário com o JavaScript.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: O tal "json" ao qual o autor da pergunta se refere já é um objeto.

Comment: Não, é um Array, por isso quando ele tenta acessa os valores com ( . ) da erro.

Comment: Justo. Mas ainda assim não é o caso de JSON.parse.